# Why does my cursor change to pointer before it is hovering an img?

Tags: html, css

```css
img {
  max-height: 89px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/x"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/F_icon.svg" /></a>
```

I want the pointer only when hovering the image, not on the anchor tag. I tried to set `width` and `height` for the `a`, but nothing has changed.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the `a` element's inline box your cursor is over. That's why it changes to a pointer in that spot.

You need to set the `a` element to `display: block` or `display: inline-block`, along with setting the `img` to `display: block`.

Comment: `display:inline-block` still gets me a margin underneath the image. The only one that really works is, strangely, `inline-flex` (?)

Comment: @Jeremy Thille: Ah yeah, I forgot you need to set the image to block as well. The reason inline-flex works is because that turns the img into a flex item and flex items by definition can't display inline.

Comment: Yep correct, it works now with `inline-block` on the image as well